# How do I change the directory for R to look for LaTeX?

Tags: r, directory, installation, latex, portability

I am having serious issues installing / working with MikTeX on my Desktop computer.

I tried installing Latex for single user and I was left with a ton of error messages saying it couldn't find 'url.sty' along with a host of other files.

I then tried to install it for all users and I would get the same error.

I tried uninstalling it and then re-installing and then I would receive an error saying that there was a file with initexmf.exe for all users, so now I couldn't install at all.

So I tried re-installing back for single user and I received a Windows API error 5 access error and I could not install at all.

Then I tried doing the portable install of MikTex and now R cannot locate a LaTeX installation.

I'm lost at what to do. I am currently installing the TeX Live as we speak so maybe that will work, but the predicted time is 4 hours for the installation.

Any tips on helping me tell R where to locate the portable version of LaTeX?

For reference, I had absolutely no trouble at all installing this to my laptop. But today, my laptop completely died and crashed. I'm very frustrated right now.

Thanks.

Comment: I switched from MiKTeX to [`tinytex`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tinytex/index.html) some time ago and have been satisfied. I've never tried LiveTeX on windows, mostly because I had read/heard "horror stories" about it (on Windows only) so opted for something with fewer complaints.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. MikTeX will work for individual files I suppose (the portable version) and tinytex will work for R studio. This is not a problem.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Though I don't use latex a lot outside of R, I don't see any reason why you couldn't add `%APPDATA%/Roaming/TinyTex/bin/` to your path. (I haven't tried it.)